# Flutter Firebase FCM not receiving messages

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using firebase messaging 10.0.8 and I have this code:

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fcm();
  }


fcm() async{
    print(await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken());
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('Got a message whilst in the foreground!');
      print('Message data: ${message.data}');

      if (message.notification != null) {
        print('Message also contained a notification: ${message.notification}');
      }
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('A new onMessageOpenedApp event was published!');
    });
  }
```

When I test this code through cloud message part on Firebase console, it doesn't work. I tried downgrading to 10.0.1, still didn't work.
I'm using Android Emulator to test my code.

Comment: Please share completely how do you initalize FCM, have you tried it on web or mobile client, emulator or real device etc. FCM setup and usage is complex, it is impossible to tell what's the problem from the info you shared.

Comment: @PeterKoltai I edited the question. I'm using Android Emulator.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not enough to help. Something is not configured properly with FCM, and nobody can tell from this code, what.

Comment: @PeterKoltai what should I do then? All other firebase functions and firestore work properly.

Comment: FCM is the most complex to setup correctly. Either check the guides and find out what are you missing, or add here the complete initialization code so that someone cloud have a look at it.

Comment: For example, on Android you need a package to display notifications when the app is in foreground. On iOS you don't. iOS emulators will not receive message, only real device. Etc.

Comment: I am trying to deploy it to test flight so I can test on real device. I can't use USB to test on Iphone, cause I dont' have a mac, and I don't have an android phone to test it on. What package do I need for Android?